How to open a PR from a Bitbucket Pipeline?
How can I use a Bitbucket Pipeline to open a new Bitbucket Pull Request for the same repo?
(Includes posting the PR description message and pushing to create the PR's source branch, or to update that branch if it is stale.)

My organization published a pipe to do that.
Because we moved away from Bitbucket, original source code was removed and the docker image is slowly aging abandonware. But it should still work.
Usage was like
pipelines:

  custom:
    create-pull-request:

      - step:
          name: Create pull-request
          script:
            - pipe: docker://calidae/bitbucket-pipe-pull-request
              variables:
                BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID:     $BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID      #(1)
                BITBUCKET_CLIENT_SECRET: $BITBUCKET_CLIENT_SECRET  #(1)
                TITLE:                   "Example title"           #(2)
                BRANCH:                  example/my-branch         #(3)
        #       TARGET_BRANCH:           master                    #(4)
        #       REVIEWERS:               '[{"username":"jane"}]'   #(5)

# ...


Mandatory since BB Pipes don't get automatic
access to all pipeline variables.
See BB documentation on how to create an API consumer key.
Pull-request title.
Source branch.
By default the target PR branch is the main branch, usually master.
Bare json, will use repository default-reviewers if unspecified.
UUID can be used instead, check Bitbucket API docs for all its possibilities.


Otherwise, write your own script to use the API, see https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-post

In any case, creating or updating the source branch is done via
git push

Does that ring any bell to you?
